# How to differentiate between T and IList<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I have two methods:

```
public static int Insert<T>(this System.Data.IDbConnection connection, T param)
public static int Insert<T>(this System.Data.IDbConnection connection, IList<T> param)
```

When I try something like this:

```
connection.Insert(new List<Foo>());
```

the wrong method (first method) is called.

How can I make it work?

Comment: try `connection.Insert<Foo>(new List<Foo>());`

Answer (score 5):

If there are generic overloads that can be implicitly called the same way, you have to use an explicit call.

This code will call the second overload.

```
connection.Insert<Foo>(new List<Foo>());
```

Answer (score 2):

This prototype:

```
public static int Insert<T>(this System.Data.IDbConnection connection, T param)
```

...will accept pretty much anything as `param` because there are zero type restrictions on it. It will accept a `Foo`, an `IList<Foo>`, a `List<Foo>` and everything non-`Foo` as well. As such, it overlaps the second prototype, a problem known as convergence.

It is best to avoid the whole mess if at all possible. If you can, define the first prototype more narrowly, like this:

```
public static int Insert<T>(this IDbConnection connection, T param) where T: Foo
```

Then it'll only be invoked when `T` is a `Foo` or a descendant of `Foo`. Neither `List<>` nor `IList<>` descend from `Foo`, so that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the generic type instead of relying on type inference

```
connection.Insert<Foo>(new List<Foo>());
```

Or you can cast your parameter explicitly to match the method's signature to help the compiler a bit.

```
connection.Insert((IList<Foo>)new List<Foo>());
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the following options:

- If you don't want to rewrite methods signature, you should help compiler to choose specific overload.

  You can either specify generic parameter

  `connection.Insert<Foo>(new List<Foo>());`

  or cast to `IList<T>`:

  `connection.Insert((IList<Foo>)new List<Foo>());`
- If you don't want to think every time you are calling the method, and if you are free to add more overloads - then easiest way is to just add overloads for all possible `IList` implementations you are going to use like this:

  ```
  public static int Insert<T>(this IDbConnection connection, List<T> param)
  {
      return connection.Insert((IList<T>)param);
  }
  ```
- If you don't want to change public interfaces at all, and still don't want to cast everywhere - you will need to change body of your most generic method to evaluate passed parameter and maybe pass it internally to other overloads, something like:

  ```
  public static int Insert<T>(this IDbConnection connection, T param)
  {
      if (typeof(T).GetInterfaces()
        .Any(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>)))
      {
          // method info retrieval should be written more carefully & cached in static var
          var method = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.GetMethods()
            .Single(m => m.Name == "Insert" && m.GetParameters()
              .Select(p => p.ParameterType)
              .Any(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>)));
          var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T).GenericTypeArguments[0]);
          return (int)generic.Invoke(null, new object[] { connection, param });
      }

      ...
  }
  ```
- Ok, if you don't like it all - just do like that guys from .NET team and rename overload to `InsertRange` or something like that. In most cases it's most convenient solution if you're designing public library.